# Add line in .txt update or if line does not exist does not work

Tags: c++, filesystems

I'm trying to write a program that replaces a specific line with a word in it or if the line doesn't exist in the file it should add it. Kind of like a key value store.

I played around with the following code, unfortunately nothing came of it. Either he just overwrote the file and deleted the other lines, or he just didn't write anything at all. Finally, this code remained. It's inefficient and confusing, I know that but maybe you can help me.

!!! at the moment he is not writing anything to the file!!!

Code:

```cpp
void edit(char*key, char*value){
            ifstream filein("test.txt");
            ofstream fileout("tempTest.txt");
            if(!filein || !fileout)
            {
                cout << "Error opening files!" << endl;
                return;
            }
            bool found = false;
            string line;
            while(getline(filein, line))
            {
                if(line.find(key) == 0)
                {
                    fileout << key << "=" << value << endl;
                    found = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    fileout << line << endl;
                }
                if(!found)
                {
                    fileout << key << "=" << value << endl;
                }   
            }
            filein.close();
            fileout.close();
            remove("test.txt");
           }
```

Comment: Yes, I have the code in a function, but I didn't write it here

Comment: ... or read everything line by line into a `std::vector<std::string>` change strings as necessary and write the whole stuff back.

Comment: Not the issue, but there's no reason for the parameters to be non-const: Every access to them is a read access and without declatring the parameters `char const*` instead of `char*` you cannot call the function passing a string literal without a `const_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop, you keep writing

```
fileout << key << "=" << value << endl;
```

in every iteration, until your key is found.

That line should be outside of the loop.